# One host server, one public IP, multiple DNS names to link multiple Virtual machines

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have one Windows 2008 R2 server hosting four virtual machines and I need each virtual machine to host a site with a unique DNS name.

On the host server, I have just one public IP, so all these DNS names are really linked to the same public IP address.

How can I redirect the request by each DNS name to the right virtual machine?

Probably there are multiple ways to do this, but as I told you the sever is hosting four virtual machines, and I would need to optimize it in order to avoid overload the host server.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You want to set up a [reverse proxy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2010/04/02/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr.aspx) on the public IP and have it direct traffic based on domain name to the appropriate internal IP. In this case, you would point the DNS records for each unique site to the reverse proxy and have it handle the redirection/load balancing.